# Python crawler can't find element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I was practicing the crawler by using `Python`.

My target is to find the test date on [GRE website](https://ereg.ets.org/ereg/public/workflowmanager/schlWorkflow?_p=GRI).

Here is what I've done now.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request

gre_url = 'https://ereg.ets.org/ereg/public/testcenter/availability/seats?testId=30&testName=GRE+General+Test&location=Taipei+City%2C+Taiwan&latitude=25.0329636&longitude=121.56542680000007&testStartDate=April-01-2017&testEndDate=May-31-2017&currentTestCenterCount=0&sourceTestCenterCount=0&adminCode=&rescheduleFlow=false&isWorkflow=true&oldTestId=30&oldTestTime=&oldTestCenterId=&isUserLoggedIn=true&oldTestTitle=&oldTestCenter=&oldTestType=&oldTestDate=&oldTestTimeInfo=&peviewTestSummaryURL=%2Fresch%2Ftestpreview%2Fpreviewtestsummary&rescheduleURL='
data = urllib2.urlopen(gre_url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print soup.select('div.panel-heading.accordion-heading') # return []
```

However, it seems that it can't extract the element `div.panel-heading.accordion-heading` from `data`.
How do I fix it?

Comment: When I'm trying to go to the URL from which you are fetching data it's redirecting to main page.

Comment: Based on the URL you're scraping, I see the option `isUserLoggedIn=true`. Setting this to false - `isUserLoggedIn=false` - will not invoke a redirection to the main page. Then, you should be able to access the element you want.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar yeah you are right, I can't access it with incognito mode, either.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr It seems not work, I still can't get that page which I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in *multiple steps visiting subsequent URLs* before making the final get requests to check the availability. Here is something that works for me using [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


start_url = "https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/register/centers_dates/"
workflow_url = "https://ereg.ets.org/ereg/public/workflowmanager/schlWorkflow?_p=GRI"
seats_url = "https://ereg.ets.org/ereg/public/testcenter/availability/seats"
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}

    session.get(start_url)
    session.get(workflow_url)
    response = session.get("https://ereg.ets.org/ereg/public/testcenter/availability/seats?testId=30&testName=GRE+General+Test&location=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States&latitude=40.7127837&longitude=-74.00594130000002&testStartDate=March-27-2017&testEndDate=April-30-2017&currentTestCenterCount=0&sourceTestCenterCount=0&adminCode=&rescheduleFlow=false&isWorkflow=true&oldTestId=30&oldTestTime=&oldTestCenterId=&isUserLoggedIn=true&oldTestTitle=&oldTestCenter=&oldTestType=&oldTestDate=&oldTestTimeInfo=&peviewTestSummaryURL=%2Fresch%2Ftestpreview%2Fpreviewtestsummary&rescheduleURL=")#

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    result = json.loads(soup.select_one('#findSeatResponse')['value'])
    for date in result['sortedDates']:
        print(date['displayDate'])
```

Of course, change the last URL to the desired one.

Comment: That is awesome!  Thanks. You have been a great help!